# How do I find an equation of the lowest possible degree with rational coefficients that includes the root of (z-2+i) (multiplicity two)?

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

[image]

So I have to find an equation of the lowest possible degree with rational coefficients that includes $2-i$ as a root, of multiplicity two.

Initially I tried multiplying $(z-2+i)^2$ with other random complex linear factors. This did not work. The lowest possible degree with complex coefficients is $z^2-(4-2i)z+(3-4i)$.

I have no idea what to try next.

The answer is $z^4-8z^3+26z^2-40z+25=0$.

Sorry, I don't know how to format this properly.

Comment: Probably unhelpful answer that glides over the point of the exercise: Mathematica's `MinimalPolynomialQ` function.

Comment: You are looking for a polynomial with real coefficients. That means that the roots occur in conjugate pairs. So if (2-i) appears twice then so must (2+i) appear twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is\begin{align}\left(z-(2-i)\right)^2\left(z-\overline{(2-i)}\right)^2&=(z-2+i)^2(z-2-i)^2\\&=(z^2-4 z+5)^2.\end{align}

Comment: I just realised how to comment on this. Thank you :D